# How to redirect to new page using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, authentication

I have created a login form,It **POST** data to another php page via ajax and check the user name and password validation.If user name or password is wrong it it display the error message on the login form.but If user authentication is OK it should redirect to corresponding page.but now it is loading in side the login form.How to redirect this successfully ?

this is back end logic

```
if ( password_verify($password, $user['passwrd']) ) {

        $userrole=$user['role'];

        switch($userrole){
            case 'admin':
                $_SESSION['username']=$username;
                $_SESSION['role']="admin";
                // This is how we'll know the user is logged in
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                header('Location: admin-view.php');
                break;
```

This code in front end page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm= $('#login-form');
    frm.submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type:frm.attr('method'),
        url:frm.attr('action'),
        data:frm.serialize(),
        success:function(data){
          $('#feedback').html(data).fadeIn( 300 ).delay( 1500 ).fadeOut( 400 );
        },
        error:function(data){
          console.log('An error occurred !');
          console.log(data);
        }
      });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Is the php code serparated from the jquery code or not?

Comment: This only extracted codes. these are in two different pages

Comment: you will be need to redirect from javascript. BTW, i hope the code you have placed are not from single file.

Comment: @Manusha Can you serparate the code in different blocks, otherwise people (like me) will think the code is just one block. Btw php header won't help to redirect, remove that line in php and use javascript redirect

Comment: `window.location.href` doesn't work?

Comment: `header('Location: admin-view.php');` < that's not going to work since you're calling that file with Ajax - you need to do a JS redirect in the `ajax.success()` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are passing the whole page as json data yoou need to relocate to the page like

```
    success:function(data){
            if(data==true)
{
window.location.href ="/YourPag.html";
}
);
            }
```

,

Comment: what should i pass back if condition is true to compare ?

Comment: pass true or false

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect to another page in javascript
like this

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

good luck